# How does autoregression work in R?

Tags: r, autoregressive

I don't understand results of `ar()` function in R.

I made up a very simple case, Fibonacci sequence:

```
x <- c(1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55)
ar(x)
```

result is

```
Coefficients:
     1  
0.5531
```

I would expect result of 1,1 - for the model `x(n) = 1* x(n-1) + 1 * x(n-2)`

Can anyone explain me please why I don't get expected result?

Comment: Fibonacci sequence is not a stationary process. There is no way you can use `ar` or `arima` to estimate it. Be careful, auto-regressive process and difference equation are different concepts!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use `ar.ols` to estimate this non-stationary series.

From the docs,

> ar.ols fits the general AR model to a possibly non-stationary and/or
>   multivariate system of series x.

Example with your data:

```
ar.ols(x,demean=FALSE)

Call:
ar.ols(x = x, demean = FALSE)

Coefficients:
1  2  
1  1
```

Comment: The same as `ar(x, method = "ols")`. Better set `order.max=2` to get rid of warning message.

Answer (score 6):

As I said in my comment, you are going toward a wrong direction.

`ar` is assuming `x` as a stationary process `AR(p)`. The default estimation method `"yule-walker"` is a moment estimator. Please see [Yule-Walker equations of autoregressive process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model#Calculation_of_the_AR_parameters) for more.

`ar` selects order `p` by minimizing AIC. For you example Fibonacci sequence `x`, it has selected `p = 1`. The resulting coefficient, by Yule-Walker equations, matches the sample ACF at lag 1:

```
z <- acf(x, lag.max = 1)
#    0     1
#1.000 0.553
```

[image]

Since model assumption is wrong, you definitely can not get `c(1, 1)` as the answer. A crude way to get you to the right estimation is using least squares linear regression:

```
N <- length(x)
y <- x[3:N]
x1 <- x[2:(N-1)]    # lag-1 
x2 <- x[1:(N-2)]    # lag-2

lm(y ~ x1 + x2 - 1)  ## drop intercept (as you know it for sure)
#Coefficients:
#x1  x2  
# 1   1
```